# Refactoring methods and creating copies with a different name in Pharo Smalltalk?

Tags: reflection, metaprogramming, smalltalk, pharo

I am experimenting with refactoring and some custom functionality. Is there a way to copy a method to the same class as the original but under a new name? (essentially creating a really shallow copy) You can do this by hand by editing the method source, but can it be done programatically?

For example:

```
doMethodName: anArgument
^ anObject doThat with: anArgument
```

becomes:

```
doNewMethodName: anArgument
^ anObject doThat with: anArgument
```

Comment: I also wished, _Duplicate Method_ was part of the standard refactoring operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compile methods by sending a `compile:` message to the target class.

1. retrieve the method

   - e.g. `method := Float>>#cos` or `method := Float methodNamed: #cos`
2. retrieve the source code

   - `method sourceCode` will return the method code as a string
   - `method ast` (or `method parseTree`) will return the code as parsed tree representation
3. Compile code into a class (optionally with protocol)

   - `TargetClass compile: sourceCode`, or
   - `TargetClass compile: sourceCode classified: protocol`

So if you have

```
Something>>doMethodName: anArgument
    ^ anObject doThat with: anArgument
```

You can do

```
code := (Something>>#doMethodName:) sourceCode.
"replace all matches"
newCode := code copyReplaceAll: 'doMethodName:' with: 'doNewMethodName:'.
"or just the first"
newCode := code copyWithRegex: '^doMethodName\:' matchesReplacedWith: 'doNewMethodName:'.
Something compile: newCode.
```

### Using AST

`sourceCode` returns the code as string, which isn't the nicest to manipulate.
If you just want to change the method name, you can rename it in the AST, e.g.

```
tree := (Something>>#doMethodName:) parseTree.
tree selector: 'doNewerMethodName:'.
Something compile: tree newSource.
```

Comment: The AST one is very cool, the one with the simple replace I think will also replace stuff inside the source if it uses the same method call there.

Comment: @unmircea I've added a regex variant to replace only the first match. String replacements are often easier when doing this by hand. Using AST is often more robust.

Comment: `methodSelector := self class compiler parseSelector: sourceCode.`can be handy to extract the selector if you want to find/replace it next.

Comment: AST way is indeed nicer but for quick and dirty generator of lots of methods based on some external data for example, 

`stream := WriteStream on: String new.
  
  stream
   nextPutAll: (
'{1}
 ^ privateProperties at: ''{2}''.' format: {  accessorName. key });
   cr.
   
  sourceCode := stream contents.` and then compiling is quick and works nicely.

Comment: #asValidSelector is also nice to turn crappy input into a decent selector.

Comment: Or `String streamContents: [ :stream | stream nextPutAll: ... ]` to avoid all the conversions and instantiations.