# Generate test method with their body in pharo

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I advanced a little in my code but I find myself facing another problem for two days. I would like to generate a test method using only the source code. But I have no idea how to do it.

I have a method that allows me to build the name of a test method but I can't write in it.

```
buildSelectorFor: aMethod
    ^ String streamContents: [:i || capitalize |
        capitalize := true.
        i << 'test'.
        aMethod selector do: [:charactar |
            charactar= $:
                ifTrue: [ capitalize := true ]
                ifFalse: [ capitalize
                            ifTrue: [ 
                                capitalize := false.
                                i << charactar asUppercase. ]
                            ifFalse:[ i << charactar ]]]]
```

so if I execute this method with this for example:

```
buildSelectorFor:Car>>#speed:mark:
```

I get this:

```
testSpeedMark
```

my goal is to get something like

```
testSpeedMark
    self assert:....equals:...
```

I added a method writeTestMethod.

```
writeTestMethod: aMethod with: anObject 
    ^(self buildTestSelectorFor: aMethod),'
      |classMethod setter instObject method|
      classMethod := aMethod methodClass.
    setter := (classMethod  allSelectorsInProtocol: #setter) asArray.
    instObject := classMethod new.
    (setter with: anObject do: [:set :ivar | instObject  perform: set with: ivar]).
     self assert: instObject class equals: (classMethod new) class.'
```

So here is what I get:
[image]

I don't know how to integrate the parameters of writetestMethod in the code I want to generate

Comment: Hello, Your explanation make me thinks a the concept of reflection. Could you check in this article if it make sens for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676239/refactoring-methods-and-creating-copies-with-a-different-name-in-pharo-smalltalk

Comment: That's not what I wanna do. thanks anyway

Comment: The description of the problem is a little convoluted, it is not clear to me if you don't know how to compile the generated method into a Class or if you didn't managed to put the values of `aMethod` and `anObject ` into the generated method, or both. Can you elaborate?